# Finding the largest divisor

Tags: c, division

A single natural number n is read from standard input. Among the natural numbers less than n, find the one whose sum of divisors is the largest. In calculating the sum of the divisors of a given number, the number itself should not be taken into account.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int n, n1, divisor = 0, sum = 0, largestSum = 0, final = 0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    //for (int i = n; i > 0; i--)
    //{
        n1= n- 1;
        while (n 1< n && n1 > 0)
        {
            divisor = n1 - 1;
            while (divisor> 0)
            {
                if (n1 % divisor== 0)
                {
                    sum = sum + divisor;
                    divisor--;
                    
                    if (sum > largestSum)
                    {
                        largestSum = sum;
                        n1 = final;
                    }
                }
                else if (n1 % divisor != 0)
                {
                    divisor--;
                }
            n1--;
            }
        }
    //}
    printf("%d",final);
        
}
```

I'm trying to shuffle around every number lower than n (lets say 10) and first I overflowed somewhere and now I'm getting 9 instead of 8 which is supposed to be the correct answer. What can I do?

Comment: `n1 = final;` does not look right, probably you want `final = n1;`

Comment: it still overflows somewhere, says **time limit exceeded**

Comment: “Time limit exceeded” does not mean an overflow occurred. You should use a more efficient algorithm. Thoughtful use of the prime factorization of the number will lead to an efficient algorithm.

Comment: `while (n 1< n && n1 > 0)` is a syntax error

Comment: You said with input n = 10 you get 9 but 8.  I am getting 0 with your code after fixing the syntax error.  Please update question with a test case.

Comment: Should that `n1--` be in the outer while loop?

Comment: Initializing `sum`, `largestSum`, and `final` to 0 doesn't work if your number is negative (which you allow with `int`).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the following issues:

1. Check return value of `scanf()` otherwise `n` may be uninitialized.
2. Your algorithm doesn't work for n < 0.  Use `unsigned` instead of `int`.
3. Syntax error `n 1`
4. `sum` should be reset in the outer loop
5. `n1--` is decremented in the wrong loop
6. `else if (n1 % divisor != 0)` is always true so just use `else`.
7. `final` is never assigned value (other than initialization)
8. (optimization) largest possible divisor is `n1/2`.
9. (optimization) no need for loop to check `n1 < n`.  We assign it that way and only decrement `n1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    unsigned n;
    if(scanf("%u",&n) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    unsigned divisor = 0;
    unsigned final = 0;
    unsigned largestSum = 0;
    unsigned n1 = n - 1 ;
    while (n1 > 0) {
        divisor = n1 / 2;
        unsigned sum = 0;
        while (divisor> 0) {
            if (n1 % divisor== 0) {
                sum = sum + divisor;
                divisor--;
                if (sum > largestSum) {
                    largestSum = sum;
                    final = n1;
                }
            } else {
                divisor--;
            }
        }
        n1--;
    }
    printf("%u",final);
}
```

and example run:

```
10
8
```

I suggest you further refactor it like this:

1. Use `for()` looks when possible.  The relevant information on the loop variable is in one place.
2. Minimize scope of variables.
3. Use a helper function `divisor_sum()` to document what is going on.
4. Use a struct `struct` to document how the `n` and `sum` value of the result are are tightly coupled.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned divisor_sum(unsigned n) {
    unsigned sum = 0;
    for(unsigned d = n/2; d; d--)
        if(!(n % d))
            sum += d;
    return sum;
}

int main (void) {
    unsigned n;
    if(scanf("%u", &n) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    struct {
        unsigned n;
        unsigned sum;
    } result = { 0, 0 };
    for(n--; n; n--) {
        unsigned sum = divisor_sum(n);
        if(sum > result.sum) {
            result.n = n;
            result.sum = sum;
        }
    }
    printf("%u", result.n);
}
```